# Proof of an inequality (maybe using mean value theorem)

Tags: calculus, inequality

Suppose that $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a twice differentiable function. The inequality is given by
$$|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h|\leq \frac{h^2}{2}|f''(\eta)|$$
where $x,x+h\in [a,b]$. The aim is to prove that there is a $\eta \in[a,b]$ such that above inequality holds.

I'm guessing that the proof can be derived using some kind of mean value theorem. But I haven't figure it out yet.

Comment: Lagrange remainder theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is twice differentiable on $[a, b]$ then for $x, x+h \in [a, b]$ we can compute its Taylor approximation with Peano remainder
$$
f(x+h) = f(x) + h f'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(\xi),
$$
for some $\xi \in [x, x+h] \subset [a, b]$. We shuffle things around, take the absolute value and get
$$
\lvert f(x+h) - f(x) - h f'(x) \rvert = \left \lvert \frac{h^2}{2} f''(\xi) \right \rvert \tag{I} \label{i}
$$
Now let
$$
\eta = \underset{\xi \in [a, b]}{\arg \max}\, \lvert f''(\xi) \rvert.
$$
By definition $\eta \in [a, b]$ and 
$$
\left \lvert \frac{h^2}{2} f''(\xi) \right \rvert \leq \left \lvert \frac{h^2}{2} f''(\eta) \right \rvert, \quad \forall \xi \in [a, b]
$$
which we insert into \eqref{i} to derive
$$
\lvert f(x+h) - f(x) - h f'(x) \rvert \leq  \left \lvert \frac{h^2}{2} f''(\eta) \right \rvert
$$
for all $x, x+h \in [a, b]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm so dumb